# Referências perdidas na hora da persistência

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Abaixo seguem minhas entidades e seus relacionamentos:

Encomenda:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "encomenda")
@XmlRootElement(name = "objeto")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Encomenda {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-z]{2}\\d{9}[A-z]{2}", message = "O código não é válido")
    @Size(min = 13, max = 13, message = "É permitido 13 caracteres")
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 13)
    @NotBlank(message = "Nome não pode estar em branco")
    @XmlElement(name = "numero")
    private String codigo;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement(name = "evento")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "encomenda", targetEntity = Evento.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Evento> eventos;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column
    private String loja;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String erro;
```

Evento:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Table(name = "evento")
@XmlRootElement(name="evento")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Evento {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column
    @XmlElement(name="data")
    private String dataOcorrencia;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column
    @XmlElement(name="hora")
    private String horaOcorrencia;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column
    @XmlElement
    private String descricao;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column
    @XmlElement
    private String local;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column
    @XmlElement
    private String cidade;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column
    @XmlElement
    private String uf;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="evento",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @XmlElement(name="destino")
    private Destino destino;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne
    private Encomenda encomenda;
```

No banco de dados tenho as tabelas **evento** e **encomenda**. Na tabela evento tenho **encomenda_id** que é a FK. O grande problema que ao persistir o objeto *encomenda* é gerado seu id normalmente assim como na tabela evento é gerado o id, porém o campo encomenda_id está null. Alguém sabe como posso resolver ?

O objeto é preenchido através de um xml, o controller está assim:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EncomendaController {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Encomenda encomenda;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Collection<Encomenda> objetos;

    @Inject
    private EncomendaService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void novo() {
        encomenda = new Encomenda();
    }

    public void salvar() throws IOException, SOAPException {
        if (encomenda.getId() == null) {
            try {
                popularObjeto(encomenda.getCodigo());
                service.insert(encomenda);
                JsfUtils.addInfoMessage("encomenda.cadastrada");
                encomenda = new Encomenda();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            service.update(encomenda);
        }
    }

    private Encomenda popularObjeto(String codigo) throws IOException, SOAPException, JAXBException {
        String xml = RoboCorreios.consultarCodigo(codigo);

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Encomenda.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Encomenda objeto = (Encomenda) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
        final boolean objetoExiste = objeto.getErro() == null ? true : false;

        if (objetoExiste) {
            setEncomenda(objeto);
            return encomenda;
        } else {
            encomenda.setErro("Objeto não localizado");
            return encomenda;
        }
    }

}
```

Meu Serviço:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class EncomendaService extends ServiceBase {

    public void insert(Encomenda objeto) {
        this.em.persist(objeto);
    }

    public void update(Encomenda objeto) {
        this.em.merge(objeto);
    }
```

Comment: Coloca o código que preenche o objeto que é persistido no banco.

Comment: Pronto @GiulianaBezerra

Comment: Que estranho! Parece estar tudo certo. Confere tua lista de eventos no objeto encomenda pra ver se ela é preenchida com a referência do evento. Você precisaria em algum momento setar a encomenda de cada evento da lista eventos igual a encomenda passada pro insert, entende? Porque senão você não vai estar referenciando o mesmo objeto encomenda e isso pode ser a causa do problema.

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra debugando eu vi que os eventos não estão com a referência de encomenda, está null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você não associou a referência da encomenda na lista de eventos. Uma forma de fazer isso é adicionar um foreach para carregar o objeto em cada item da lista de eventos:

```
public void salvar() throws IOException, SOAPException {
        if (encomenda.getId() == null) {
            try {
                popularObjeto(encomenda.getCodigo());

                for (Evento evento : encomenda.getEventos()) {
                    evento.setEncomenda(encomenda);
                }
                service.insert(encomenda);
                JsfUtils.addInfoMessage("encomenda.cadastrada");
                encomenda = new Encomenda();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            service.update(encomenda);
        }
    }
```

Com essa mudança a mesma encomenda criada estará associada a cada um dos eventos.

Comment: Eu fiz essa mesma lógica já e vi que funcionou, mas isso não é trabalho do `JPA`? Digo porque posso me deparar com uma situação que terei muitos relacionamentos.

Comment: É trabalho do Hibernate fazer o cascade, popular os objetos é sua tarefa. Ele só iria preencher se você fizesse uma consulta no BD e o atributo estivesse mapeado. Pra persistência é o desenvolvedor que faz.